# MySQL update order (row number) from comma delimited list - the simplest way

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two columns ID and ORDER, what I want to achieve is to update ORDER column as list numbers (like 1, 2 ...).

I have input as comma-delimited list of IDs:

```
21545,13117,21538,940,19658,21547,21532,7404,19663,19666,863,13114,13121,11769,13147,13156,972,13165,13174,13182,853,19671,7429,935,1015,931,986,996,991,953,893,920,899,906,20972,886,873,21574,21548
```

I need to update ORDER so 21545 = 1, 13117 = 2 and so on.

**What is the simplest way to achieve this?**

Maybe this is an easy task for you, but I am an MSSQL developer, so please don't mind me asking this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`FIELD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function to return the position of a value in a set of values if you are building the query from scratch e.g.

```
SELECT FIELD(13117, 21545,13117,21538,940,19658)
```

If you have a string which is comma separated, you can use [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(13117, '21545,13117,21538,940,19658')
```

In both cases the output is `2`.

You can find a demo showing the use of these functions in an `UPDATE` query on [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gomUmfQ3nt7tzPcoNfdcuA/2)

Comment: thanks Nick so is this the final: UPDATE `product`
SET sort = FIND_IN_SET (id, '21545,13117,21538,940') 
WHERE id in (21545,13117,21538,940)

Comment: @DejanDozet good point, I should have included the `WHERE` clause in my demo. I'm glad this was helpful.

Comment: sure and thanks again, I am good in queries but in another platform :) hope I can remember this for the next similar case

Comment: @DejanDozet yeah - it would be great if they all used the same SQL! I find it hard to keep up...